# Media keyboard volume buttons changes VLC volume AND system volume

Tags: vlc-media-player

This only happen when VLC have focus.

Is this something I can disable? I could not find anything in the VLC preferences.

Comment: In some versions of VLC, this problem is slightly different. Only the VLC volume is affected by the media keyboard volume buttons and the system keyboard is unchanged. The fix is the same for both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known issue in VLC.  [There is an open issue for fix (hopefully) in the next release.](http://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/3828)

There is now a fix in place within VLC (as described in the link): Tools -> Preferences (Show Settings: All) Interface -> Main interfaces -> Qt and Ignore keyboard volume buttons.

Comment: No problem. Just doing a little to help people find answers to this. It annoyed the hell out of me - I'm glad that I found this answer.